# DMP integration Marketing Cloud : Email Marketing Config ID

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am setting up Audience Studio (DMP) integration in Marketing Cloud for one of my Business Units.

I have already obtained following information:

- SHA256 Hashed Email Partner Key
- Subscriber ID Partner Key

I'm missing "Email Marketing Config ID" - any idea what it is and how do I get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That field is defined as:

Email Marketing Config ID:
confid of the media tag that's used to collect email impressions/clicks